# Why is the ItemText of my CheckedListBox viewed as being "0"?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

With this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items.Count - 1); i++)
{
    if (checkedListBoxPlatypi.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        ReturnListPlatypi.Add(ParsePlatypusID(checkedListBoxPlatypi.GetItemText(i)));
    }
}
```

...and a CheckedListBox that *does* have text assigned to it via (FriendlyPlatypus is a string with content):

```
checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items.Add(FriendlyPlatypus);
```

...ParsePlatypusID() is being passed "0"...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you didn't add "i" to the listbox, so there wouldn't be any text for that object.  You just need the object directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items.Count - 1); i++)
{
    if (checkedListBoxPlatypi.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        ReturnListPlatypi.Add(ParsePlatypusID(checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items[i].ToString()));
    }
}
```

If, in fact, you had added an object through a databinding, and you wanted to get directly to the "DisplayMember" field, you would use:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items.Count - 1); i++)
{
    if (checkedListBoxPlatypi.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        ReturnListPlatypi.Add(ParsePlatypusID(checkedListBoxPlatypi.GetItemText( checkedListBoxPlatypi.Items[i])));
    }
}
```

Comment: @J: No, "Friendly Platypus" is a string like "Platypi R Us (314)/(42)", not an enum (I tried appending the .ToString() to it just for due diligence, but it made no difference).

Comment: @Clay Shannon Edited because I obviously completely missed the boat.